# Search with optional punctuation

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to configure my Elasticsearch to search a word with optional punctuation but i don't know how to do this with my settings.

For example, I search for the word "computer", but I would like to allow a pattern to search, in fact, the following words : "computer.", "(computer", "computer)", "computer,"...

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you should understand how Elastic mapping and text field works, text field in Elastic will be analyzed based on analyzer you set during the mapping, then this analyzer will be used to analyze your text and generates terms, For example if you use standard tokenizer for a text: `This computer is fast. (Computer).` these will be the result.

```
GET _analyze
{
  "analyzer": "standard",
  "text": "This computer is fast. (Computer)"
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "this",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "computer",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 13,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "is",
      "start_offset" : 14,
      "end_offset" : 16,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "fast",
      "start_offset" : 17,
      "end_offset" : 21,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 3
    },
    {
      "token" : "computer",
      "start_offset" : 24,
      "end_offset" : 32,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 4
    }
  ]
}
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "this",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "computer",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 13,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "is",
      "start_offset" : 14,
      "end_offset" : 16,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "fast",
      "start_offset" : 17,
      "end_offset" : 21,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 3
    },
    {
      "token" : "computer",
      "start_offset" : 24,
      "end_offset" : 32,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 4
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see in the result punctuation will be removed for indexing so when you search for computer with match query you will get all type of documents back, for example:

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "Your_Filed": "Computer"
    }
  }
}
```

You can check all query DSL of Elastic search [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html).